# Progress bar is not stopping

Tags: java, android

It looks like loading when website load. It is not stopping. Here is my code.

```
public void cosh2() {

        progressBar3 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
        progressBar3.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
        progressBar3.setProgress(progress);


        if(progress ==100){
            progressBar3.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
        }

        webView30 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview30);
        webView30.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView30.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView30.loadUrl("http://rangamati.gov.bd/");
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if ((keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)&&webView30.canGoBack()){
            webView30.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
```

Comment: Some code is missing, e.g. how is `progress` incremented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this way ideally you will get a callback when page is loaded you can stop showing pogess bar there.

```
public void cosh2() {

        progressBar3 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
        progressBar3.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
        webView30 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview30);
        webView30.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String url) {
        progressBar3.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

    }
});
       WebSettings webSettings = webView30.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView30.loadUrl("http://rangamati.gov.bd/");
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if ((keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)&&webView30.canGoBack()){
            webView30.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done this for one of my apps and it's working just fine

Inside **onCreate**

```
 MainActivity.this.progressBar3.setProgress(0);


    final Activity MainActivity = this;
    webView30.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
    {

    MainActivity.this.setValue(progress);
    super.onProgressChanged(view, progress);
    MainActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); 

    if(progress == 100){
    MainActivity.this.progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}


    else{
    MainActivity.this.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    });
```